# print datatable as default table

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, datatable

I have a datatable with column filter 
so thead has search inputs

I need when user print this page (Cntr + p) to print the table as a default table without the column filter and datatable arrows "remove datatable"

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in your css is define print media as follows with all the classes you want to apply or not apply when user hits Ctrl+P:

Here is an example that will eliminate all arrows from column headers

```
@media print {
    .sorting, .sorting_asc, .sorting_desc {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

In order for you to show filter text, I suggest you do the following:

1. Add a hidden text field before your filter input (refer to this
   documentation on how to insert elements in datatables
   https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)
2. Attach keyup binding to
   the filter input so that it populates your hidden text. (refer to
   this example
   [datatables global search on keypress of enter key instead of any key keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619498/datatables-global-search-on-keypress-of-enter-key-instead-of-any-key-keypress))
3. In the @media print unhide the text box and hide the filter input
   box.

Comment: thanks for your replay
but how can I convert filter input in the thead to text

Comment: Sorry about that, check my UPDATE section.