# How server side processing with DataTable works?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, express, datatables

I'm pretty new to nodejs and expressjs. I am trying to use datatables with serverside processing. I have a large number of records and I only pull 10 records from the database and display them on the screen. With the pagination method, when I go to a forward page, I pull and show the other 10 records. But I am not sure how to use the search area. While these are ready in client side processing, we need to add queries ourselves in server side processing. But the data I show on the screen comes from more than one table. I'm not sure how the searching area should work, whether this is how server side processing should work, if I'm doing the right thing. I will be grateful if you could help me.

```js
router.get('/example', async function(req, res, next) {
  const deviceType = req.session.data.deviceType;
  const pageLength = req.query.length;
  const start = req.query.start;
  const searchValue = req.query.search.value;
  const totalDeviceCount = await dbHelper.getTotalDeviceNumber(deviceType);
  const deviceList = await dbHelper.getDeviceListWithPaging(pageLength,start,deviceType);
  
let data = {
"draw": count,
      "recordsTotal": totalDeviceCount,
      "recordsFiltered": totalDeviceCount,
      "data": deviceList,
      "paging": true,
      "pageLength": pageLength,
    };
    res.send(data);
});
```

```html
<table id="exampleTable" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Version</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
let example = $('#exampleTable').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "searching": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "ajax": {
    "url": "user/example"
    },
    "columns": [
    {'data': 'DeviceType'},
    {'data': 'Version'}
    ],
    "bFilter": true,
    "lengthChange": true
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? It's not clear to me from the question. If you know how to return the "next" page of results from the server, then you should also be able to enhance that to handle filtering the data on the server (and sorting the data, and jumping to any arbitrary page number).

Comment: I tried to use server side process because there are too many records in the db. When switching between pages, I only pull the data I need from the db with a sql query. When I want to search for a data that I have not pulled from the db yet in the search section, should I do it with a sql query again and how should this search be because there are more than 5 values that I show on the screen and they come from different tables. The keyword I typed in the Search section can be a value in any table. I have no idea how to do the search part,  I asked for help on this. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Thank you for your notes - but they basically just repeat the information in your question.

Comment: If you wish to use server side processing, every action that can be taken on the client side must be supported by the server side queries and response handling, including: sort, pagination, filter, search, display, etc. To fully assist we would also need to understand how `getTotalDeviceNumber()` is defined and `getDeviceListWithPaging()`.  Also, you define `searchValue` but do not provide it to any of your model functions so how/where is it being used? Server side processing is one of the more complex features of DataTables so if you are new to DT be aware of its difficulty.

Comment: I keep more than one type of device in the database. With the getTotalDeviceNumber function, I return how many devices of the selected type I have in total. With the getDeviceListWithPaging function, I pull 10 devices from the db sequentially as I switch between the pages. I kept the searchValue variable, but I haven't done anything with this value yet because I don't know how to use it. For example, every change I make on the datatable, every letter I type in the search field causes an ajax call. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Should I use code like this?                                                                 
          $('#exampleTable')
         .on( 'search.dt', function () { } )
         .dataTable();

Comment: "_every letter I type in the search field causes an ajax call. How can I prevent this?_": A quick search led me to this and other similar questions (and answers): [datatables global search on keypress of enter key instead of any key keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619498/datatables-global-search-on-keypress-of-enter-key-instead-of-any-key-keypress). If none of these meet your needs, you can ask a new specific question - and you can clarify why these are not suitable solutions.